# Silverlight - What does my datacontext/binding path need to be here?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, datacontext

I've been working a bit with an image editor in Silverlight for the past week or so. It's my first encounter with it and I still haven't fully gotten my head around data bindings and datacontext or mvvm. I have a rotation method and I want to be able to pass the angle value from a text box on my MainPage.xaml to the method.I have an initial value set of 90 and my function rotates the image 90 degrees when I click it. The textbox is empty at runtime and also is clearly not updating my rotation angle.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=Project}" Height="70" Name="grid1" Width="200">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="35" />
      <RowDefinition Height="35" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="84*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="57*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="59*" /> 
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<Button Command="{Binding Path=RotateCWElementCommand}"
      Height="30" Name="btnRotCW" Width="30" Grid.Column="2" Margin="15,0,14,5" Grid.Row="1">
<Image Source="../Assets/Images/Icons/object-rotate-right.png" Grid.Column="1"
      Grid.Row="4" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" />
</Button>

<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,8" Text="Rotate" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,9,0,10" Text="Angle:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=RotateElement.Angle, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="24" Name="textBox1" Width="52" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,6,5,5" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

(Relevant code from)
Project.cs-

```
namespace ImageEditor.Client.BLL
{
public class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

            #region Properties
            private RotateTransform rotateElement;
      public RotateTransform RotateElement
      {
        get { return rotateElement; }
        set
        {
            rotateElement = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RotateElement");

        }
    }

        #endregion
    #region Methods


    private void RotateCWElement(object param)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = this.SelectedElement;
        RotateTransform RotateElement = new RotateTransform();

        RotateElement.Angle = 90;
        RotateElement.CenterX = element.ActualWidth * 0.5;
        RotateElement.CenterY = element.ActualHeight * 0.5;
        element.RenderTransform = RotateElement;


    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is it my datacontext or my binding path that is the problem? What should they be? Formatting is a little off sorry

Comment: You should post the code of your ViewModel.

Comment: Sorry, posted accidentally before I was done

Comment: Do you have any binding errors? (They appear in the Output window when you run the project)

Comment: No there doesn't appear to be any errors in the output window. Is my data context or binding path just wrong?

Comment: It would probably be useful to post the code which sets the DataContext of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the UI does not know that a property in your object has changed, since you only notify when your object changes, but not the properties in it:

```
 private void RotateCWElement(object param) 
 { 
        FrameworkElement element = this.SelectedElement; 
        if (this.RotateElement == null) this.RotateElement = new RotateTransform(); 

        RotateElement.Angle = 90; 
        RotateElement.CenterX = element.ActualWidth * 0.5; 
        RotateElement.CenterY = element.ActualHeight * 0.5; 
        element.RenderTransform = RotateElement; 

        //tell the UI that this property has changed
        NotifyPropertyChanged("RotateElement"); 
 }
```

Comment: The only difference this makes is that now if I type in an angle in my textbox and press the rotate button (it still rotates 90 degrees) but the textbox is cleared now. The initial value of 90 also doesn't show in my textbox when I run it first

Comment: ofcourse it wont change, you created a new RotateTransform object in this method with the same name that you want to read from, instead use your global RotateElement object like this: this.RotateElement = new RotateTransform(); I updated my anwser

Comment: Also when your appliaction starts your RotateElement is null, so your value in xaml won't bind, until that object is initialized...

Comment: Ah, I should have seen that, thanks. I also don't shouldn't be setting RotateElement.Angle = 90 as it sets it to 90 each time the method is called. It's working fine now apart from a few weird behaviours from the width and height values of the element not changing on rotation. It renders fine though and the image saves as it should. Thanks again